# Laravel 4: define json or html route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible in Laravel 4 to define a route that returns either html or json based on if `.json` is added to the request url?

Eg:

`POST example.app/user/new` would respond with a `Redirect::to` another route giving html

`POST example.app/user/new.json` would respond with a `Response::json` response giving json

Is it possible to achieve this? And if so how?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinNabiałek. Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
Route::post('user/new{extension?}', function($extension = null)
{
    switch ($extension) {
        case '.json':
            return Response::json();
            break;

        default:
            return Redirect::to('/');
            break;
    }
});
```